# Grouping results by test

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table with this structure:

```
Test    Value   Shape

1       1,89    20
1       2,08    27
1       2,05    12
2       2,01    12
2       2,05    35
2       2,03    24
```

I need a column for each Test value, in this case, something like this:

```
 Test 1         | Test 2

Value | Shape   | Value | Shape
```

I tried to do this with pivot, but the results wasn't good. Can someone help me?

[]'s

Comment: This is display logic, not database logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways that you can get the result since you are using SQL Server.  In order to get the result, you will first need to create a unique value that will allow you return multiple rows for each `Test`.  I would apply a windowing function like `row_number()`:

```
select test, value, shape,
  row_number() over(partition by test
                    order by value) seq
from yourtable
```

This query will be used as the base for the rest of your process.  This creates a unique sequence for each `test` and then when you apply the aggregate function you are able to return multiple rows.

You can get your final result using an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select 
  max(case when test = 1 then value end) test1Value,
  max(case when test = 1 then shape end) test1Shape,
  max(case when test = 2 then value end) test2Value,
  max(case when test = 2 then shape end) test2Shape
from
(
  select test, value, shape,
    row_number() over(partition by test
                      order by value) seq
  from yourtable
) d
group by seq;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ecca/1).

If you want to implement the PIVOT function, then I would first need to unpivot your multiple columns of `Value` and `Shape` and then apply the PIVOT.  You will still use `row_number()` to generate a unique sequence that will be needed to return multiple rows.  The basic syntax will be:

```
;with cte as
(
  -- get unique sequence
  select test, value, shape,
    row_number() over(partition by test
                      order by value) seq
  from yourtable
) 
select test1Value, test1Shape,
  test2Value, test2Shape
from
(
  -- unpivot the multiple columns
  select t.seq,
    col = 'test'+cast(test as varchar(10))
          + col,
    val
  from cte t
  cross apply
  (
    select 'value', value union all
    select 'shape', cast(shape as varchar(10))
  ) c (col, val)
) d
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for col in (test1Value, test1Shape,
              test2Value, test2Shape)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ecca/2). Both versions give a result:

```
| TEST1VALUE | TEST1SHAPE | TEST2VALUE | TEST2SHAPE |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|
|       1,89 |         20 |       2,01 |         12 |
|       2,05 |         12 |       2,03 |         24 |
|       2,08 |         27 |       2,05 |         35 |
```